# Azure DevOps : Error Message The Service Hooks service was unable to send the notification to the target consumer

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-service-hooks

​We have created some service hooks in Azure DevOps which get triggered during as soon our Release Pipeline is succeeded. However, we have noticed that these service hooks fail abruptly with the message. To give a context, the Service Hook executes a custom API which in turn calls a bunch on Azure DevOps REST APIs.

> Error Message The Service Hooks service was unable to send the
> notification to the target consumer. Error Details Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object. (activity Id is
> f928eefe-3eaa-0000-6bc9-8f832ebdd601).

We do not have any further information apart from the one mentioned above. We are trying to understand under what circumstance this can happen. Can somebody throw some light as to what might lead to issues like this one?

Comment: Are you using azure devops on-premise server? Could you share the action configuration of the service hook (eg. post url and the http headers)?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT : I am using Azure DevOps. The trigger action is Release Deployment Succeeded. We have not used any custom headers, but the Post URL is a custom URL. The URL is not even getting triggered and we get this error. The curious case is this happens only for the Release Deployment action and not for the Pull Request actions.